# UIRefreshControl appears multiple times on pulling again

Tags: uitableview, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I am having a `UIRefreshControl` in my `tableView` and when I pull it, service is called. Problem is, If I have pulled is once and service is being called and meanwhile, I pull it again, I see another refresh control.

Here is the code I used to define refresh control:

```
// Pull To Refresh Code
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
[self.myTableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

My `handleRefresh` method:

```
-(void) handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *) refreshControl{
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateBlogList)];
}
```

In my `updateBlogList` method, I am calling my service and when I get response, I use  `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing]`.

And if I pull again before this line executes, there are basically two refresh controls on screen.

How I can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every pull, you create a a new `refreshControl` with the line

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
```

This is why you have a new one created every time the pull is made, and it also is added to the subview. Perhaps you should use lazy initialization for it to make sure that if the object has been created already, you will not be creating a new one:

```
if (self.refreshControl == nil) {
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
}
```

And this way it's assigned to the property right away, so you don't need the `self.refreshControl = refreshControl` line.

Or, you could set a flag and and unset it when you call `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing]`, and if the flag is set, the Pull to Refresh code won't execute at all.